# Linux Stack trace dump

Tags: c++, g++

I'm coding a program and at some point during execution it crashes and print this stack-trace:

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
0  prog            0x08f04a98
1  prog            0x08f05147
2                  0xb7802400 __kernel_sigreturn + 0
3  libc.so.6       0xb758fbb2 abort + 386
4  libstdc++.so.6  0xb778653f __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 335
5  libstdc++.so.6  0xb7784405
6  libstdc++.so.6  0xb7784442
7  libstdc++.so.6  0xb77850f5
8  prog            0x08f2cb1f proj::raw_ostream::write(char const*, unsigned int) + 159
9  prog            0x081df8fe
10 prog            0x081d079b
11 prog            0x08e8ac02 proj::Value::~Value() + 130
12 prog            0x082749ad
13 prog            0x08e1cd62 proj::Tiny::~Tiny() + 178
14 prog            0x08e1fc86 proj::Alloca::~Alloca() + 38
15 prog            0x08e252ac proj::Alloca::~Alloca() + 44
16 prog            0x088e9bbc
17 prog            0x088e9b64
18 prog            0x08d3782e
19 prog            0x08d36a46
20 prog            0x08d34e95 proj::Medium::~Medium() + 485
21 prog            0x08d34c9c proj::Medium::~Medium() + 44
22 prog            0x08d3753c
23 prog            0x08d36da4
24 prog            0x08d350ed proj::Medium::eraseFromParent() + 109
25 prog            0x08dc780d proj::Big::dropAllReferences() + 253
26 prog            0x08e530b9 proj::Module::dropAllReferences() + 137
27 prog            0x08e52ea0 proj::Module::~Module() + 64
28 prog            0x08c602cb proj::Engine::~Engine() + 155
29 prog            0x08743e00 proj::Controller::~Controller() + 192
30 prog            0x08743d2c proj::Controller::~Controller() + 44
31 prog            0x081cdee9
32 libc.so.6       0xb75912df
33 libc.so.6       0xb759134f
34 libc.so.6       0xb7578cae __libc_start_main + 238
35 prog            0x081cc501
```

What is the address on the third column? I guess they are function address but are they? seems that some virtual function is being called at somepoint, how do I know what virtual function is being called?

Comment: Compile your program with debug information (`-g` flag of g++), you will get more accurate information from the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

The third column is the program counter recorded on the stack so it will be a code address.

You need to look at whether you are calling pure virtuals within your destructors; most likely `proj::Value::~Value()` is calling a virtual that is pure in `proj::Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are function addresses. If you have the corresponding core file for that dump, and you had compiled with debugging symbols, you can load the core and executable in `gdb`, and use the command `list *<address>`. It will show you the line of code corresponding to that address.

Without seeing any code, I would guess `write` on `raw_ostream` is a virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

The third column is the actual memory address that is being executed on the function stack (should be equal to the fourth column, which gives you the offset from the beginning of the named function).

The function stack is shown growing up: lines shown earlier are nested deeper in the call stack.  In other way: your `main` is near the bottom of the list

The virtual function is called from `proj::Value::~Value()`, which calls `proj::raw_ostream::write(char const*, unsigned int)`, which causes the exception